# Get a specific url from a list with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<p class="URL-List">
    Download : 
    <a href="https://exampleAA.com"><strong>AA</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleBB.com"><strong>BB</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleCC.com"><strong>CC</strong></a>
</p>
```

My Code

```
AA = URL[0].getElementsByTagName("a")
AA[0]
```

I will get the first URL:

> https://exampleAA.com

But the list changes

```
<p class="URL-List">
    Download : 
    <a href="https://exampleCC.com"><strong>CC</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleDD.com"><strong>DD</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleSS.com"><strong>SS</strong></a> /
    <a href="https://exampleAA.com"><strong>AA</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleFF.com"><strong>FF</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleBB.com"><strong>BB</strong></a>
</p>
```

My Code

```
AA = URL[0].getElementsByTagName("a")
AA[0]
```

Now I get: `

> https://exampleCC.com

`
But I want

> https://exampleAA.com

How can I find that specific URL?

Comment: unclear how you are supposed to get that URL. What do we have that gives us any idea you need that URL?

Comment: What function is calling the Javascript? What event triggers your js? How are you indicating which url to return?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) with [attribute selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) if you know which link you want:

```js
let myLink = document.querySelector("a[href='https://exampleAA.com']");

console.log(myLink.textContent, myLink.href);
```

```html
<p class="URL-List">
    Download : 
    <a href="https://exampleCC.com"><strong>CC</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleDD.com"><strong>DD</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleSS.com"><strong>SS</strong></a> /
    <a href="https://exampleAA.com"><strong>AA</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleFF.com"><strong>FF</strong></a> / 
    <a href="https://exampleBB.com"><strong>BB</strong></a>
</p>
```

[Do not use `.getElementsByTagName()` in 2020.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474)

Comment: @3limin4t0r The link in my answer covers all the attribute selectors and is exact the same link you added.